# Python Multiprocessing with pool running only 400 jobs out of 2000 and getting stopped

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

I want to run a code module on 2000 separate data. For that I have used the following python code

```
num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() 
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_workers)
print 
results = [pool.apply_async(run_Nested_Cage, args=(bodyid,)) for bodyid in body_IDs]
output = [p.get() for p in results]
```

Its running fine for 50 data in body_IDs but when I am giving 2000 bodies its starts running fine but after generating results for 424 bodies the programme is getting stopped without any error.

I am running it in AWS EC2 linux ubuntu server with 8 core 32 GB ram and 100GB storage.

Can anyone help me to identify the solution?

Comment: Did you have a look at the resource allocated for each process? The most obvious answer would be that it ran out of RAM memory... although a memory error should be raised. I'm saying that since if it works for 50, it should work for more, except if objects remain in memory and in the end saturate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either a memory issue, an uncaught exception, or code complexity issue.

1. Add some "debug" logs you can disable later
2. Instead of one enormous pool, try rotating among a pool of pools
3. Occasionally terminate a pool instance to free up memory
4. Run some profilers

Profilers:

- [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)
- [cpu-profiler](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)